# How to build an OpenFire Client based on JavaScript and Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, openfire

Since I played around with OpenFire Server, I started to make up my mind to build an IM Client connecting to this Server. So, I quickly do some research on this by looking for any library based on JavaScript with Flash. Unfortunately, I cannot find any. Does anybody know where to get source? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

dude, check out strophe. that is what you look for ! i plan to use it myself

Comment: Strophe is the way to go. Look into OpenFire's http-bind/BOSH tools. http://www.malcollier.com/?p=14